# Is there a difference between Espirando and Mancando?

Tags: dynamics, interpretation

I've seen both these terms listed in online music glossaries as meaning "dying away", but neither entry ever refers to the other. Are there any real-world differences in how these are interpreted?

Comment: In which pieces of music have you seen these terms? The typical musical term I see for "dying away" is smorzando.

Comment: Both Italian, both meaning 'dying away, 'expiring'. Can't find any more info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FWIW, the go-to [Dolmetsch](https://www.dolmetsch.com/defss3.htm) page says
espirando

> (Italian) fading away, expiring, dying away, spirando, en expirant

mancando

> (Italian) failing, diminishing in strength, dying away, lacking

smorzando

> (Italian) extinguished, put out, gradually dying away to a whisper,
>   calming down, subduing (Italian ) in music, similar terms include al
>   niente (Italian), morendo (Italian), dämpfend (German), abschwächend
>   (German), bis zum Nichts (German), en amortissant (French), hasta la
>   nada (Spanish)

The basic answer is that composers use the word(s) they want to, and there's a ton of overlap in the multitude of semicommonly used descriptors.

Comment: Doesn’t *morendo* also mean something similar?

Comment: @ToddWilcox - another Italian word for dying. Maybe that's a common thing to do there?!

Comment: I typically understand "al niente" to mean dying away to literally nothing, not the p/pp/ppp of smorzando.

Comment: All this answer has done really is to quote Dolmetsch. Little has been added. Google Dolmetsch.

Comment: I didn't accept this answer primarily for its Dolmetsch quotes, I accepted it for "The basic answer is that composers use the word(s) they want to, and there's a ton of overlap in the multitude of semicommonly used descriptors"